# Can't access users in sandbox using instagram api

Tags: instagram-api

I have created a client in Instagram and I have 2 users in its sandbox. I can successfully authorize my client and receive data from `self` endpoint. But When I try to change the user to the ones in the sandbox I receive a page that says

> Sorry, this page isn't available.
>
> The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been
>   removed. Go back to Instagram.

For example when I try this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self?access_token=TOKEN
```

I receive a proper response, however when I change the user:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/sudomakeinstall2?access_token=TOKEN
```

I receive `the page isn't available`.

**Note that the user is indeed in the sandbox**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `username`, it should be `user-id` in place of `self`.

user-id for username @sudomakeinstall2 is `422703870`

replace `sudomakeinstall2` with `422703870` and try API call